# Adding calculated line to the same list

Tags: python, list, append, line, extend

I have a file with data, i.e.

```
2 3 5 6
```

I want to calculate (2+3)/5 and extend the resulting value after 6 with \'t'. i.e

```
2 3 5 6 1
```

How to do this? I wrote a code, but it only appends the value at the end of list
I get smth like this

```
2 3 5 6
 1

f=open('file', 'r')
lines=f.readlines()
import re 
for line in lines:
    new_list=re.split(r'\t+',line)
    a=new_list[0]
    b=new_list[1]
    c=new_list[2]
    d=new_list[3]
    y=((float(a)+float(b))/float(c))*100
    y=round(xy,1)
    y=str(y) 
    new_list.append(y)
    r=open('result', 'a')
    x='\t'.join(new_list)
    x=x+'\n'
    r.writelines(x)
f.close()
r.close()
```

Comment: By the way you can shorten it by `a, b, c, d = new_list`.

Comment: can you add the output you get with this code?
the calculation in the code is ((a-b)/c)*100. not (a+b)/c. on purpose?

Comment: in addition, `x` is a string, you might want to use `r.write(x)`

Comment: since I gave a sample example instead of my actual data I made some typing error, anyway I get result like 2 3 4 6 and from new line 1

Comment: You probably forgot to strip the '\n'. `readlines()` doesn't strip this, it just splits on it. So, use something like `new_list=re.split(r'\t+',line.strip())`.

Comment: @Evert or just don't use a regex and use `line.split()` which will...

Comment: @JonClements True, but I'd like to start with what the OP has. In fact, there's a lot of code that can be improved, but for that I would suggest putting this code up at codereview after it's fixed.

Comment: thank you Evert,I was missing that detail! works!

Comment: @user3224522 Excellent. See my comment above about codereview. You may learn a lot more from that :-).

Comment: thank you!Going to do it right now

Comment: @user3224522 I think it is better that you add answer to your question with the solution. for other people who will see this question.

Comment: the solution is that I added this line new_list=re.split(r'\t+',line.strip()), anyway I posted the whole answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat unrelated to your attempted solution, but it's how I'd approach the problem. I really try to avoid regex when possible, and it's definitely possible to do so in your case.

The first line takes your file and names it f (and automatically closes the file when we're done with it). Then I split your data and put it into a list, splitting each time there's a space. Initially, the output is strings, so I make those into floats. Then I do the weird calculation you want based on the numbers in my list, and print the output.

```
with open('nums.txt','r') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    list_of_nums = line.split(" ")
    myNums = [float(num) for num in list_of_nums]
    weird_calculation = (myNums[0] + myNums[1]) / myNums[2]
    print(str(weird_calculation) + "\t" + str(myNums[3]))
```

Output:

```
1.0     6.0
```

If you want only some of these numbers to be treated as floats and others as ints, you'll have to explicitly change that.

Answer (score 0):

Just added a line.strip, sometimes this tiny things make it all work

```
f=open('file', 'r')
lines=f.readlines()
import re 
for line in lines:
    new_list=re.split(r'\t+',line.strip())
    a=new_list[0]
    b=new_list[1]
    c=new_list[2]
    d=new_list[3]
    y=((float(a)+float(b))/float(c))*100
    y=round(xy,1)
    y=str(y) 
    new_list.append(y)
    r=open('result', 'a')
    x='\t'.join(new_list)
    x=x+'\n'
    r.writelines(x)
f.close()
r.close()
```